# Xtext - Read in text file and use words in proposal provider

Tags: dsl, xtext

I try to read in a txt file with one word each line. This should be done only at program start up.
Furthermore, I would like to use this words as proposals.

Is this possible?
Im quite new to Xtext and Xtend so I dont know how to solve it by my own.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it really doesn't need to be refreshed when it changes and it has a fixed URL, then you could simply do this during static initialization of the ProposalProvider class.